# C file not reading properly

Tags: c, text, io, stream

When I run the following command in the command terminal: `gcc practice.c temp.txt`

I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/binutils/2.21/bin/ld:temp.txt: file format not recognized; treating as linker script
/usr/local/binutils/2.21/bin/ld:temp.txt:1: syntax error
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Here is my C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_LEN 1024

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  FILE *file;
  char line[MAX_LEN];
  float value = 0;

  file = fopen(argv[1], "r");

  while (fgets(line, MAX_LEN, file) != NULL) {
    sscanf(line, "%f", &value);
    printf("%f\n", value);
  }

  fclose(file);

  return 0;
}
```

Basically I am trying to read numbers in a file and just print them out. Very simple.

For example, temp.txt will just be something like:

10
26
27
52
242

(these numbers should be in a column)

and so forth.

Comment: The error message is telling you exactly what the problem is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use gcc to compile the executable, and then run the executable on the input file afterwards.  You get an error b/c gcc is trying to compile your test.txt as C source code.

So:

```
gcc practice.c -o practice
./practice test.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But what does the ./ notation do?

Comment: I assume the directory you are in is not part of your `PATH` env variable.  The `./exename` notation says to run the executable named `exename` that is found in the current directory.  If you do not do that, and if '.' is not in your `PATH`, then a Unix-like OS will not find the executable to run it.

Comment: The `./practice` notation means run the code in the file `practice` located in the current directory, which is typically not on your `PATH`.

Comment: Ah ok I see thanks. I found out I could just run it by doing practice test.txt

Comment: The ./ is a path notation. The "." mean the current directory, the "/"  is used to separate the name of the directory to the other directories or file after it. With this command, you ask your computer to run the "practice" program located in your current folder.

Answer (score 2):

You may need some explanation about what gcc really is, gcc is used to translate your code into a runnable program, it's a sort of translator for code to executable instruction for your computer.

You do not need to compile the text file, you first need to compile your program :

```
gcc practise.c -o your_binary_name
```

then launch it with your file in parameter :

```
./your_binary_name temp.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

C is a *compiled* not an *interpreted* language.  GCC does not *run* the code as say *Python* or other *scripting languages* can for example.  GCC rather translates the C source code to native machine code that when *linked* to the target runtime to create an *executable* is then separately and directly loaded and executed by the operating system without support from GCC at all.